# Trouble creating error message in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, raiserror

I have the following piece of code within my `stored procedure`, I know it doesn't work and should not work but I wanted to illustrate my intentions:

```
 declare @ErrorMessages varchar;
 set @ErrorMessages = 'An existing deposit on this property ends after the intended start date for the new deposit. ' +
    'Existing End Date: ' + @PreviousDepositEndDate + '. Intended Start Date: ' + @TenancyAgreementStartDate
  raiserror 50002 @ErrorMessages
```

Can anyone tell me what I should be doing? Or any links on creating this type of string.

EDIT: Forgot to say that the @Dates are both of `datetime`, the error message is that it cannot be converted from datetime to string

Comment: Specify a size for `@ErrorMessages` - How does it not work? What error is displayed, what types are @PreviousDepositEndDate et al.

Comment: @AlexK. Forgot to say its a datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly different version which some people like because it emulates C printf style:

```
-- Test data
declare @PreviousDepositEndDate varchar(30) = cast(getdate() - 1 as varchar(30))
    , @TenancyAgreementStartDate varchar(30) = cast(getdate() as varchar(30))
-- Throw
raiserror (N'An existing deposit on this property ends after the intended start date for the new deposit. Existing End Date: %s. Intended Start Date: %s',
           16, -- Severity,
           1, -- State,
           @PreviousDepositEndDate, -- First argument.
           @TenancyAgreementStartDate) -- Second argument.
```

More info can be found in this MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 declare @ErrorMessages varchar(255);
```

Using just `@ErrorMessages varchar;` gives you a `varchar(1)`.

```
set @ErrorMessages = 
      'An existing deposit on this property ends after the intended start date for the new deposit. ' + 
      'Existing End Date: ' + 
      @PreviousDepositEndDate + '. Intended Start Date: ' + @TenancyAgreementStartDate

  raiserror(@ErrorMessages, 16, 1)
```

If you wan't to specify the error number, you must first use `sp_addmessage` and define the error message, which you can reference in `raiserror`. You may have to insert some casts, depending on what types `@PreviousDepositEndDate` and `@TenancyAgreementStartDate` are.